# Why do we need an interrupts when using a battery charger?

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, charger, interrupts

I am analysing a circuit, containing a battery charger. In the schematic, it says that our battery charger sometimes performs an interrupt on the microcontroller.

What is the reason?

**UPDATE**

The circuit does not discuss about the structure of the battery charger circuit (battery charger is just a small section of our circuit). So I do not know anything about the battery charger circuit. I just need some general reason for that.

Comment: Depends on the battery charger. Show us the datasheet for the battery charger. Common reasons are so the charger can tell the microcontroller something happened - it doesn't have to be "urgent"

Comment: There may be many reasons but we can't know what the charger output pin signals to MCU what does the MCU do before or after it receives this signal.

Comment: This question is far too vague to be answered reliably. Please edit your question and add plenty of detail about the equipment you have, it's purpose and function, plus a schematic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A subsystem will issue an interrupt to a controller when it needs to asynchronously indicate a service request.

Any reasonably complex subsystem will have logic that will need to be serviced either periodically (e.g. every minute to obtain a status) or asynchronously (e.g. when the plug is removed or full charge achieved). An interrupt is the classic service request indication in a controller system.

The details of the service request and how to manage it is specific to each type of subsystem, and absent a specification defining the interface for a large number of devices often to the specific type of controller .

The service handling can be done in a number of ways, through direct interface with the microcontroller I/O, via a secondary interface like I2C or other popular chip to chip serial bus to some secondary embedded logic, or it could be just a status update and take no action. This is defined by the architecture and intended purpose of the system.

This answer would apply to many other embedded subsystems, battery controllers, LED controllers, protocol adapters etc. In fact, even when systems are integrated on-die in SoC micro-controllers, the internal interrupt logic remains in the system on a chip network.

It is ubiquitous and universal, like a register or a pointer in software, even though more complex variants of both of those also exist.

Comment: As an addendum, having an interrupt doesn't always mean having to do something even if it asks you, as a system designer you could ignore the interrupt or only check the status when you have free CPU (thus risking some gap if there is an important event). Having an interrupt does not imply a closed loop control with the controller, but in some cases it does.

Comment: This is just a description of interrupts and answers the general question 'Why use interrupts'. It doesn't address the actual question as asked, which cannot be answered reliably as it contains practically no specific details. Downvoting for that reason, I'm afraid.

Comment: @TonyM no arguments it is too vague for EE, I flagged it to move to system engineering SE unless question is changed.

Comment: Thanks and that's good action to take. In light of that, I removed my downvote (had to edit your question to do so, though).

Comment: @crasic - Hi, "*I flagged it to move to system engineering SE*" There is no "system engineering SE" and I can't think where on SE the question is suitable, in its current form. It asks about a specific circuit, but doesn't provide the schematic :(